# Cycles. in viewport render nothing renders. in Render, file reverts back to some older version of a mesh

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, materials, rigging

Working with the spring rig from Blender Spring rig : (CC:BY) , Blender foundation. Voice clip from | Bad sisters | Sharon Horgan

Springs old hair is coming back through even though I deleted part of it and edited and sculpt and changed color. I looked through shape keys, modifiers and can’t figure it out.

When I try to to a viewport render I’m getting all black.

File https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N_oK5PV-RqRgC4-GVBR5BoPJqdpgrwQN/view?usp=share_link

K[image]